# If condition with AWK giving incorrect output

Tags: shell, if-statement, awk, yaml

Here is a snippet of a code ,I am expecting the result to be printed as Failed but it ends up giving me Ok message instead. I have cross checked and crontab entry does have the string that the code is searching for. NR ==0 should be false as I understand, what is the purpose of $0<1   ?

Crontab entry as seen :

```
# comment x

00 5 * * * /opt/vol/scripts/volumes.sh -m SOP
```

Code:

```
shell: |
  crontab -l | grep -v "^#" | grep "/opt/vol/scripts/volumes.sh" | grep "SOP" |
  awk 'END { if (NR==0 || $0<1) print "OK - sop job not scheduled"; else print "FAILED - sop job should not be scheduled"; }
```

Incorrect Output:

```
OK - sop job not scheduled
```

Expected Output:

```
FAILED - sop job should not be scheduled
```

Comment: Why it should not be scheduled ? Your input contain `SOP`

Comment: @GillesQuenot- We have several systems where such crontab entries were scheduled in the past, now the recent update is to make sure that none of the systems have these entries anymore , which is why the above check was included . Im just curious here to know what would be the output of $0<1, as questioned above.

Comment: Your `awk` way is awkward. Better use my response... If you can't read/understand this snippet, your colleagues will not too. Not maintenable and not expected behavior.

Comment: @GillesQuenot not sure whether you understand the question or made an effort to understand what's written in the code, the part  "if (NR==0 || $0<1)"  was to return  false value but ends up returning the opposite which is why the out put is also printed wrongly. Your answer does not remotely answer my question.

Comment: I make no effort, because this is not readable and clear code. Anyway, the condition `NR==0` means there's no lines at all in the input. The part `$0<1` is strange.  @Ed Morton to the rescue :D Maybe incorrect way to write: `length($0) < 1`

Comment: Since the value of `$0` is undefined in an `END` section, `$0<1` could mean/do anything and it doesn't make sense with respect to what your grep commands could output so my best guess (and it really is just a guess) is that whoever wrote it thought they were writing shell instead of awk and wanted to check if the exit status of the previous command was success.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton, it's like I said, incorrect use of `awk`.

Answer (score 2):

To simplify:

```
if crontab -l | grep -Eq "^\s*[^#].*/opt/vol/scripts/volumes\.sh.*SOP"; then
    echo "OK - sop job scheduled"
    exit 0
else
    echo "FAILED - sop job should not be scheduled" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

If it's not the expected `echo`'s, edit the `echo`'s lines

Comment: Should probably change `crontab -l | grep -q  "/opt/... ` to `crontab -l | grep -Eq "^\s*[^#].*/opt...` so cron comments are not included.